# How to order html elements by content of a children using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have something like:

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <p>......</p>
    <span class="author">Deena</span>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="outer">
    <p>......</p>
    <span class="author">Amanda</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to order the div.outer using the value of the span.author.

So far I managed to code the following:

```
  var mylist = $('#outer-wrapper');
  var mylist2 = $('#outer-wrapper2');
  var listitems = mylist.find('.outer span.author');
  listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).html().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).html().toUpperCase());
  })
  $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist2.append(itm); });
```

The thing is this just adds to #outer-wrapper2 the span items instead of the whole div.outer.

How can I make it work how I want?

Thanks!

Comment: from itm, select the ancestor that you want to move. Note, you don't need the $.each

Comment: Yeah. appending `item.parent()` instead of item would probably do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to sort the `.outer` elements, and inside the sort function, do the sorting based on the returned HTML from `.author` :

```
var mylist  = $('#outer-wrapper .outer').get(),
    mylist2 = $('#outer-wrapper2');

mylist.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('.author').html().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).find('.author').html().toUpperCase());
});

mylist2.append(mylist);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/39q3m/)